Boolean modifiers of geometry node interact weirdly with imported STL
What I'm trying to do:

Import STL of a Wing
Apply Geometry nodes doing simple booleans to
extract ribs

Blender File
Result:
Resulting ribs have no volume and missing 2d faces

Fixes I've tried:

Remesh (resulted in booleans not matching any geometry)
Intersect Boolean of Wing with gigantic cube
Fix Non-Manifold (Not sure if I did this correctly)


(Using Blender 4.2.5)

Figure 1: Initial faces orientation.
The Mesh Boolean node fails because the normals on the pressure side of the wing are pointing inside (see Fig.(1)). To check that normals are pointing outside, in Viewport Overlays check the Geometry > Face Orientation option. If correct, all faces must be blue for a manifold surface. To visualize normals in Edit Mode, check also the Mesh Edit Mode Overlays > Normals option choosing Display Normals.

Figure 2: Faces orientation after update.
In Edit Mode, select all faces then go to the menu entry Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside (shortcut Shift N) (see Fig.(2)).

Figure 3: Ribs made with the Mesh Boolean node "Intersect" operation.
With proper normal orientation, the GeometryNodes modifier is extracting ribs with correct face orientation and thickness (see Fig.(3)). It is to notice that the STL mesh is open at the trailing edge. Consequently, the inside is visible as red in Fig.(3). To check manifold mesh, in Edit Mode with Vertex selection mode go to the menu entry Select > Select All By Trait > Non Manifold.
Resources:

Blender file: (Blender 4.2.5+)
Viewport Overlays documentation
Mesh Edit Mode Overlays documentation
About manifold surface: see What is non-manifold geometry?

